# Using Sklearn with NumPy and Images and get this error 'setting an array element with a sequence'

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, python-imaging-library, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to create a simple image classification tool.

I would like the code below to work with classifying images. It works fine when it is a non image NumPy array.

```
#https://e2eml.school/images_to_numbers.html
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
from PIL import Image
 
monkey = [1]
dog = [2]

example_animals = Bunch(data = np.array([monkey,dog]),target = np.array(['monkey','dog']))
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2) #with KMeans you get to pre specify the number of Clusters
KModel = kmeans.fit(example_animals.data) #fit a model using the training data , in this case original example animal data passed through
import pandas as pd
crosstab = pd.crosstab(example_animals.target,KModel.labels_)
print(crosstab)
```

I have looked into how to make an image into a NumPy array at https://e2eml.school/images_to_numbers.html 
The code below where I have converted images to NumPy array doesn't work.
When run it gets the following error

** 'setting an array element with a sequence'**

```
#https://e2eml.school/images_to_numbers.html
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
from PIL import Image
    
monkey = np.asarray(Image.open("monkey.jpg"))
dog = np.asarray(Image.open("dog.jpeg"))

example_animals = Bunch(data = np.array([monkey,dog]),target = np.array(['monkey','dog']))
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2) #with KMeans you get to pre specify the number of Clusters
KModel = kmeans.fit(example_animals.data) #fit a model using the training data , in this case original example animal data passed through
import pandas as pd
crosstab = pd.crosstab(example_animals.target,KModel.labels_)
print(crosstab)
```

I would appreciate any insight how I fix the error 'setting an array element with a sequence' so that the images will be compatible with the sklearn processing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that your images "monkey.jpg" and "dog.jpeg" have the same number of pixels. Otherwise, you will have to resize the images to have the same size. Moreover, the data of your Bunch object need to be of shape (n_samples, n_features) (you can check the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.fit)

You need to be aware that you use an unserpervised learning model (Kmeans). So the output of the model is not directly "monkey" or "dog".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to error **setting an array element with a sequence**
Kmeans requires the data arrays for comparison need to be the same size.
This means if importing pictures, the pictures need to be resized, converted into a numpy array (a format that is compatible with Kmeans) and finally made into a 1 dimensional array.

```
#https://e2eml.school/images_to_numbers.html
#https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-and-manipulate-images-for-deep-learning-in-python-with-pil-pillow/

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pandas as pd

monkey = Image.open("monkey.jpg")
dog = Image.open("dog.jpeg")

#resize pictures
monkey1 = monkey.resize((180,220))
dog1 = dog.resize((180,220))

#make pictures into numpy array
monkey2 = np.asarray(monkey1)
dog2 = np.asarray(dog1)

#https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-image-data-from-2D-array-to-1D-using-python
#make numpy array into 1 dimensional array
monkey3 = monkey2.reshape(-1) 
dog3 = dog2.reshape(-1) 

example_animals = Bunch(data = np.array([monkey3,dog3]),target = np.array(['monkey','dog']))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2) #with KMeans you get to pre specify the number of Clusters
KModel = kmeans.fit(example_animals.data) #fit a model using the training data , in this case original example food data passed through
crosstab = pd.crosstab(example_animals.target,KModel.labels_)
print(crosstab)
```